# How can I split the same function in two parts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have the following structure, just an example:

```
   (function number1( $ ) {
                    $.fn.abcd = function( options ) {

                            heyyou.find(".123").css({});
                            heyyou.find(".456").css({});

 var delay = 1000;
 var site = "http://url";
 setTimeout(function(){   window.location.href = site; },delay);}
$("#button").on('click', function(){ window.location.href = site;});

                    return this;
                }( jQuery ));
```

And what I believe I need to do is something like this:

```
//part1
(function number1( $ ) {
                    $.fn.abcd = function( options ) {

                            heyyou.find(".123").css({});
                            heyyou.find(".456").css({});

                    return this;
                }( jQuery ));
//part2
(function number1( $ ) {
                    $.fn.abcd = function( options ) {

 var delay = 1000;
 var site = "http://url";
 setTimeout(function(){   window.location.href = site; },delay);}
$("#button").on('click', function(){ window.location.href = site;});

                    return this;
                }( jQuery ));
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is:
"part1" is going to be inside a js file that's going to be placed inside the header. "part2" is a function that I need to call from a `<script></script>` later on the DOM.
The thing is that both parts are using the same main function, one is continuing the other.

For example:

```
<script src="part1.js"></script>

<body>

<script>//part2</script>
<button id="button">Do something</button>
</body>
```

So basically I want the function to start in the js file, then I'll finish it from another part. I'm not sure how to explain this, it's just that I need the `var site` to be called separately, as I'm going to use the same script for different pages, I need each page to call for the `var site` with a different value.

Basically it's a redirect script, so I can't use the same redirection url for every page.

EDITED:

The structure needs to be like this:

mainjs.js:

```
<header>
 <script>
//part1
(function number1( $ ) {
                    $.fn.abcd = function( options ) {

                            heyyou.find(".123").css({});
                            heyyou.find(".456").css({});

                    return this;
                }( jQuery ));
</script>
</header>
```

Page 1:

```
//part2                                
var site google
```

Page 2:

```
//part2
var site bing
```

Page 3:

```
//part2
var site yahoo
```

"//Part1" is executed first and is executed in every page.
"//part2" is executed later and each page will have a different url to redirect to, inside "//part2" function.

In reply to Ehsan:

It would have to be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function function1(site) {
  //redirect to site
  alert(site);
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
function function2() {
  // Do your css thing here.
  site = "http://somethingelse";
  function2(site);
}
</script>
<button onclick="function2()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Edit - 3

You are looking for something like this.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert(site);
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var site = "google.com";
</script>
```

You can create two separate functions, chain them and use global variables to pass the data between them.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" >
var site = "http://url";
function function1() {
  // Do your css thing here.
  site = "http://somethingelse";
  function2();
}
</script>
<button onclick="function1()">Click me</button>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function function2() {
  //redirect to site
  alert(site);
}
</script>
```

Edit: You can also pass data by using parameter in function, then you don't need to use the global parameter. It depends on the use case, but I assume passing as a parameter is a much cleaner option.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" >
function function1() {
  // Do your css thing here.
  site = "http://somethingelse";
  function2(site);
}
</script>
<button onclick="function1()">Click me</button>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function function2(site) {
  //redirect to site
  alert(site);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: functionnumber2 is not defined

Comment: Please provide code examples of what you are doing, it's extremely confusing when you just post an error message. I am assuming you moved the second function to an external script and included it in HTML. Make sure you also don't copy the script tag in js file.

Comment: And use this [site](https://beautifier.io/) to prettify the code before you post, if you can. It's a little unreadable, what you posted on the first post.

Comment: I'm not allowed to share the code publicly, that's why. But I can provide it through dm.

Comment: Also, I need site to be defined in the second function, as the second function is the one that's going to have a different version in each page. Can you point me how?

Comment: Does function1 have to run before function2, or the chronology doesn't matter?

Comment: Sir, you created something from back to front... "//part1" needs to be executed first. I'll edit the question, so it's better understandable.

Comment: Edited. Please verify.

Comment: Added another rendition

Comment: Dude, honestly, I have given you both version, where part2 is triggering first, and where part 1 is triggering first. I think you are not even sure what you want yourself. I won't spend my time here anymore.

Comment: I'm pretty sure of what I want, not my fault if you couldn't understand me. Your first solution was the closest one to what I described.